# how to represent values at each step of gradient descent of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Given a positive definite symmetric matrix $A$ and a function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T A x + x^T b + c$$

we know that the Hessian matrix of $f$ is $A$, which is a constant and positive definite. Hence, the stationary point of $A$ is a global minimum and its value is given by $f(-(A+A^T)^{-1}b)$. Suppose the eigen values of $A$ are $\lambda_1>...>\lambda_n$. Define the square distance from the optimum

$$d(x_k) = \| x^{\ast} - x_k \|_2^2$$

where $x^{\ast}$ is the value of $x$ that minimizes $f(x)$ value return by gradient descent and $x_k$ are the values computed in each gradient decent steps. i.e

$$x_k = \nabla f(x_{k-1}) \alpha + x_{k-1}$$

for some learning rate $\alpha$. How do we represent $d(x_k)$ in terms of the eigenvalues, eigenvectors, $x_0$(initial guess) and $k$?

I got this recursive formula:

\begin{align*}
x_{n+1} \\
    &=x_n-\triangledown f(x_n)a \\
    & = x_n -\alpha(Ax_n+b) \\
    & = (I-\alpha A)x_n -\alpha b \\
    & =(I-\alpha A)((I-\alpha A)x_{n-1} - \alpha b )- \alpha b \\
    & = (I-\alpha A)^2x_{n-1}-(I-\alpha A)\alpha b -\alpha b \\
    &= (I-\alpha A)^{n-1}x_0 -(I-\alpha A)^{n-2}-...-\alpha
\end{align*}

Furthermore, is there a sufficient condition that guarantees that the sequence $d(x_k,x*)$ converges to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity?

Here is what I tried: the optimal value using matrix multiplication is :
\begin{align*}f(x_{min})\\
    &=-\frac{1}{2}b^T(A^{-1})^TA(-1)(A)^{-1}b-(A^{-1}b)^Tb+a \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}b^T(A^{-1})^Tb-b^T(A^{-1})^Tb+a \\
    & = -\frac{1}{2}b^TA^{-1}b+a\end{align*}. So now we have to compute the distance $( \frac{1}{2}b^TA^{-1}b+c-x_k)^T( \frac{1}{2}b^TA^{-1}b+c-x_k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reread yourselves...

$\min(f)$ is reached for $x^*=-A^{-1}b$. Then we show that $x_k$ tends to $x^*$.

Let $U=I-\alpha A$. Then

$x_{k+1}=U^{k+1}x_0-(U^k+U^{k-1}+\cdots+I)\alpha b$.

Note that $||U||_2=\max_{\lambda\in spectrum(A)}|1-\alpha\lambda|$. We choose $\alpha>0$ s.t. $||U||_2<1$.

Then $U^k$ tends to $0$ and $U^k+U^{k-1}+\cdots+I$ tends to $(I-U)^{-1}$ when $k$ tends to $\infty$.

Finally, $x_k$ tends to $-(I-U)^{-1}\alpha b=-A^{-1}b$.  $\square$

Comment: pardon me, how is it the case that if the 2-norm of a matrix is less than one then the two norm of the power of the matrix tends to 0 as the power increases to  infinity? Can you refer some readings on that? Also, why the inverse of $U$ exists?

Comment: i) $||U^k||\leq  ||U||^k$. ii) The eigenvalues of $I-U$ are the $(1-\alpha\lambda)$. If $\alpha$ is small enough, then these eigenvalues are non-zero and $I-U$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you sir! umm can you also explain why is the 2- norm of a matrix the  max of $|1-\alpha \lambda|$? Here $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue right?

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases

Comment: sorry sir, is this how we write the distance $d_(x_k)$ using spectral decomposition of $A$ and recursive formula of $x_k$? can we simplify it?  $$( \frac{1}{2}b^TPD^{-1}P^Tb+c-( (I-\alpha PDP^T)^{n-1}x_0-((I-\alpha PDP^T)^{n-2}+...+I)\alpha b))^T( \frac{1}{2}b^TPD^{-1}P^Tb+c-( (I-\alpha PDP^T)^{n-1}x_0-((I-\alpha PDP^T)^{n-2}+...+I)\alpha b))$$

Comment: You did not reread yourselves! $d(x_k)=||x_k-x^*||$ and not $||x_k-f(x^*)||$. $x_{k+1}=U^{k+1}x_0-(I-U^{k+1})(I-U)^{-1}\alpha b=U^{k+1}x_0-(I-U^{k+1})A^{-1}b$ and $x_{k}-x^*=U^{k}(x_0+A^{-1}b)$.